# Integrals depending upon a parameter

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

There was an exercise, in my professor's book, asking to prove the continuity of an integral depending upon a parameter. Namely, the hypothesis were:
Let $D$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$, and let $f:D \times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ such that

- $\exists \lim_{t\to t_0} f(\vec x, t) = g(\vec x)$
- The function $\vec x \mapsto f(\vec x, t)$ is measurable in D $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$ and exists a summable function $h:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(\vec x, t)|\leq h(\vec x)$ for almost any $\vec x$ in $D$ and $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$
  Then 
  $$\exists \lim_{t \to t_0}\int_D f(\vec x, t) d \vec x = \int_{D} g(\vec x)d\vec x $$

Now, my question is: can't the second hypothesis be eliminated? My reasoning was that if $$\lim_{t \to t_0} f(\vec x, t)=g(\vec x)$$
then $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta > 0:|t-t_0|<\delta \implies |f(\vec x, t)-g(\vec x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{m_n(D)}$, where $m_n(D)$ is the Lebesgue measure of D. But then $$g(\vec x) - \frac{\epsilon}{m_n(D)}<f(\vec x,t)<g(\vec x)+ \frac{\epsilon}{m_n(D)}$$ for $t$ sufficiently close to $t_0$, so $$\int_D g(\vec x)d \vec x - \epsilon<\int_D f(\vec x, t)d \vec x<\int_D g(\vec x)d\vec x + \epsilon$$ and we're finished. Is there something wrong with my reasoning? Thank you guys!

Comment: a) The $\delta$ would depend on $x$. b) $D$ may have infinite measure. Even if you exclude sets of infinite measure, a) still doesn't allow your argument.

Comment: Oh yeah, makes sense. Thank you. Could the argument be fixable asking for some sort of uniform convergence of the function then? (and supposing the set has finite measure). Just checking

Comment: Yes, if you have uniform convergence and finite measure, the argument works.

Comment: Then, for proving the first statement, does this work? Let's consider the sequence: $t_n=t_0+\frac{1}{n}$. We have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_D f(\vec x, t_0+1/n)d \vec x=\int_D g(\vec x) d \vec x$ because of the dominated convergence theorem. Let's call $\int_D f(\vec x, t)d \vec x = I(t)$ and $\int_D f(\vec x, t_0+\frac{1}{n})d \vec x=I(t_0+1/n)$. If the limit $t \to t_0$ exists, then it is certainly equal to the other one because of the "bridge theorem" (the one that correlates limits of sequences and functions). But we have proven it exists, so we're finished.